# React hooks linting : Does it always make sense?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-hooks

As you probably know, create-react-app 3 comes with a new eslint rule : `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`. When a dependency is missing from the dependency array of a hook, a warning is shown. But this doesn't always seem to make sense.

Some dependencies might be "silent" or "weak" dependencies.

In a code, I have the following case :

```
const Project = ({ id, '*': tab }) => {
  const [{ openProjects }, { openProject, setProjectTab }] = useStore()

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if(find(openProjects, { id }))
      setProjectTab(id, tab)
    else openProject(id, tab)
  }, [tab])

  return (...)
}
```

which gives me :

> Line 98:  React Hook useLayoutEffect has missing dependencies:
>   'id', 'openProject', 'openProjects', and
>   'setProjectTab'. Either include them or remove the dependency array 
>   react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

`openProject` and `setProjectTab` are constant functions, they always point to the same references, so I could include them in the array to shorten the warning. No issue.

But `openProjects` is an array from my global state that is handled like in redux : everytime there is an update, a new array is created.

**But**, that update precisely happens as an *effect*, which would create an infinite update loop if I were to add it as a dependency.

So :

- Obeying the linter rule : infinite loop.
- Not obeying the linter rule : annoying warning.

Am I wrong with my design or is `exhaustive-deps` really too restrictive and should consider the concept of *weak* dependencies (ie. **don't** trigger the effect on change) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some effect depends on a result of some computation, e.g. `find(openProjects, { id })`, but not on arguments for that computation, then it's possible to make it **explicitly** dependent only on the result of that computation, e.g. by extracting a variable:

```
const isFound = find(openProjects, { id })

useLayoutEffect(() => {
  if(isFound)
    setProjectTab(id, tab)
  else openProject(id, tab)
}, [isFound, setProjectTab, openProject, id, tab])
```

I would recommend to keep the eslint rule enabled and think harder about the *minimum set of all dependencies* that could influence code execution results.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem. When I use hooks, I only include variables that change in the dependency array, I do not include constants or data that I know doesn't change.

You can use `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks / exhaustive-deps` to disable the linting for the next line.